# TCP Sampler changing the text while sending message

Tags: jmeter, pos

I am sending a text by TCP sampler in Jmeter for POS testing(ISO8583) as below:

> 02441200.0..... .......*19000608032XXXXXX663900100000000000000900000000007340322018053017210620180530200067000020000007340320000000042056636SREESVAGENCIE  28SREESVAGENCIESPEDDAPURAMAPININR005CPYBK3101         140     915555577860003POS005NFNET002NP

But when it is received at the server it is supposed to come as:

```
30 32 34 34 31 32 30 30 f0 30 81 01 08 e0 80 20 
00 00 00 00 04 00 00 2a 31 39 30 30 30 36 30 38 
30 33 32 58 58 58 58 58 58 36 36 33 39 30 30 31 
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 39 30 
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 37 33 34 30 33 32 32 
30 31 38 30 35 33 30 31 37 32 31 30 36 32 30 31 
38 30 35 33 30 32 30 30 30 36 37 30 30 30 30 32 
30 30 30 30 30 30 37 33 34 30 33 32 30 30 30 30 
30 30 30 30 34 32 30 35 36 36 33 36 53 52 45 45 
53 56 41 47 45 4e 43 49 45 20 20 32 38 53 52 45 
45 53 56 41 47 45 4e 43 49 45 53 50 45 44 44 41 
50 55 52 41 4d 41 50 49 4e 49 4e 52 30 30 35 43 
50 59 42 4b 33 31 30 31 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 
20 31 34 30 20 20 20 20 20 39 31 35 35 35 35 35 
37 37 38 36 30 30 30 33 50 4f 53 30 30 35 4e 46 
4e 45 54 30 30 32 4e 50
```

But it is coming as:

```
30 32 34 34 31 32 30 30 2e 30 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 20
2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2a 31 39 30 30 30 36 30 38
30 33 32 58 58 58 58 58 58 36 36 33 39 30 30 31
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 39 30
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 37 33 34 30 33 32 32
30 31 38 30 35 33 30 31 37 32 31 30 36 32 30 31
38 30 35 33 30 32 30 30 30 36 37 30 30 30 30 32
30 30 30 30 30 30 37 33 34 30 33 32 30 30 30 30
30 30 30 30 34 32 30 35 36 36 33 36 53 52 45 45
53 56 41 47 45 4e 43 49 45 20 20 32 38 53 52 45
45 53 56 41 47 45 4e 43 49 45 53 50 45 44 44 41
50 55 52 41 4d 41 50 49 4e 49 4e 52 30 30 35 43
50 59 42 4b 33 31 30 31 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 31 34 30 20 20 20 20 20 39 31 35 35 35 35 35
37 37 38 36 30 30 30 33 50 4f 53 30 30 35 4e 46
4e 45 54 30 30 32 4e 50
```

Kindly let me know if there is any specific setting to be done in Jmeter to send the ISO Request.

Answer (score 0):

some fields in iso8583 are fixed length, if you feed these fields with less data than it expected, it will padded the the remain.In your example seems message fields are padded with 0x2E.Also this could be because of differences on ISO8583 protocol version in server and terminal.As you know some fields length are changed in ver1993 compared to ver1987.